# Python: How to format the output from colored(var, 'color')

Tags: python, formatting, termcolor

I'm currently outputting the term 'var' in my program, with the following formatting.

```
print(time,'\t{0:8f}\t'.format(var))
```

I've managed to output the var in color, depending on different conditions and I've got that to work, however, I can't format the output to the same formatting as above!

```
if(condition1==True):
  print(colored(var,'green'))
```

I've tried print(colored(var, 'green').format({0:8f})) and it hasn't worked. Does anyone know how to format colored outputs?

Comment: What does "It hasn't worked" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
var = 1.2345
print(colored('\t{0:8f}\t'.format(var), 'green'))
```

The idea is use `format()` to create the formatted string first, then feed that into `colored()`.

`colored()` wraps the given string in ASCII escape sequences that control the color. You can also do it like this:

```
print(colored('\t{0:8f}\t', 'green').format(var))
```

which passes the format string to `colored()` and then passes that to `format()` for variable substitution.